# Does Drizzle provide an API to close database connection?

Tags: drizzle

Here is my script to seed the database using `Drizzle`,

```js
import { drizzle } from "drizzle-orm/postgres-js";
import postgres from "postgres";
...

const client = postgres({
  host: ...,
  port: ...,
  database: ...,
  username: ...,
  password: ...,
  max: 1,
});

const db = drizzle(client);
await db.insert(students).values([{ name: "Mark" }]);

// closing the connection by calling PostgresJS, it will hang without this line
client.end();
```

Note that I have to call `end()` from `PostgresJS` client to close the connection.

Is this the only way to close the connection? Does `Drizzle` provide an API to close database connection?

Answer (score 2):

Ran in to a similar issue and I don't think Drizzle does...

You can configure the client to set a timeout when idle, using the `idle_timeout`  setting. [From the Postgres documentation](https://github.com/porsager/postgres#connection-timeout):

> By default, connections will not close until `.end()` is called. However, it may be useful to have them close automatically when...

My solution was to export both `db` and `client` and run a `.finally` on the `db` promise:

```
db.select().something().finally(() => client.end())
```